# Wordpress Nested Taxonomy Query using wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

In Wordpress I have a Custom Post Type, called Properties, and a Taxonomy called Buildings which is linked to the Properties. I also have another custom Taxonomy called Amenities. A building can have many different amenities.

I want to be able to do a single wp_query (to cater for pagination etc) on the Properties that allow advanced filtering on the Amenities. However, it would appear that since the Amenities are linked to the Buildings, and not the Property that I cannot do a query on the Properties that returns the Amenities filter.

Am I correct in this assumption? And that I would really need to link the Amenities to the Property as well (not ideal at all).

So a simple tax_query like:

```
array_push($args['tax_query'], 
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'amenities',
        'field'     => 'term_id',
        'terms'     => 54
    )
);
```

Does not work. It doesn't actually matter what the Building is in this instance. Is there any way of achieving this inner join?